# Extension for Datagridview row to pass the value for SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, sqldatatypes

I made a datagridview and I need to pass my datagridview data to a SQL Server database. For that I have created all the codes and after a button click I want to pass those value so I made a code following but it is giving me an error that this does not contain a definition for `.Text` and no extension method for text. It is giving me an error line under `.Text` so what is the correct extension method for text.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Adding Values to Data Base
   string mySQL = "INSERT INTO Employee_login VALUES ("
     + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[0].Text.Trim()) + ", '"
     + dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[1].Text.Trim() + "','";
}
```

Comment: `.Value()` is what you are looking for.  But, you cannot call `.Trim()` on it.  Do you have to trim the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be calling the `.Value` property on your `dataGridView1`, not the `.Text` property.

Something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Adding Values to Data Base
  string mySQL = "INSERT INTO Employee_login VALUES ("
   + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[0].Value) + ", '"
   + dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[1].Value + "','";
}
```

You didn't mention in your post however, if you actually **need** to call the `.Trim()` method; which will not work in this case using `.Value`.

Comment: I am glad that I could help!  Mind giving my answer an upvote too, please?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this to databind. You will not have to manually enter values into the database if so.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Your connection string");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Employee_login", conn);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

On the button click event you can provide something like

```
dataAdapter.Update(dt)
```